# Java String TRIM function not working

Tags: java, android, string

I am receiving a string from server trailing one or two lines of spaces like below given string.

```
String str = "abc*******         
          ********";
```

Consider * as spaces after my string

i have tried a few methods like

```
str = str.trim();

str = str.replace(String.valueOf((char) 160), " ").trim();

str = str.replaceAll("\u00A0", "");
```

but none is working.
Why i am not able to remove the space?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Rest assured: trim() is working. But we cant help to spot the problem in your code on such input. In other words: provide a **real** [mcve] that allows us to repro the problem.

Comment: Are the character really spaces? Or some special characters? And is that a linebreak inside your string?

Comment: i  have edited my question @f1sh that is a string receiving from server side

Comment: @sonam, we would really need a better idea of what the actual string is, rather than one where you have replaced characters with other arbitrary asterisk characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\n", "").trim();
```

You can observe there is a new line in that string . first replace new line  "\n" with space("")  and than trim

Comment: I do not understand. The documentation clearly states that `trim` should remove any character less than the decimal value 20 in Unicode. `\n` has a decimal representation of 10, therefore trim should remove it and this should not help. Also, and maybe this is a pointless quibble, but `""` is not space, `" "` is. `""` is empty.

Comment: i know but as per her question i understand there was a new line ,so trim was not working there

Comment: `'\n'` is a newline. `trim` should always remove newlines.

Comment: yeh but it is not working ,thats why this is a alternate situation

Comment: I guess I have two different points to make. Firstly, if someone told you (for example) "I have a variable `x` which is equal to `5`, then I type `int y = x;`, but then when I print `y`, it prints out `7`, what am I doing wrong?", it would not be logical to tell them "Try this: `int y = (int)(((double)x) / 15 * (7 + 8) - 2 - 3 + 5);`". By the definition of the language, those are functionally equal, and in the same way, it doesn't make sense that removing newlines first could have an effect on trailing whitespace if you are calling `trim` anyway.

Comment: My second point is that what you are proposing doesn't actually answer the question, as it will remove all newlines in the whole string, even if they are validly there and not part of trailing whitespace. This has a very high potential to lead to unintended bugs for the original poster, as they did not indicate that this functionality was desired in their program.

Comment: okay than just tell me why trim is not working there ,when the string is with trailing 1-2 lines of spaces ????

Comment: Well, I encourage you to test it yourself, like this: `"test               \n              ".trim()` and you will see that the result is `"test"`. Seeing as the original poster does not specify what he means by "not working" by giving an example, I can only believe that he thinks the input string should look a certain way, and is using that to determine what he thinks the output should look like, and is seeing a different result than that. If this is the case, most likely his input string does not contain what he thinks it does.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

In my case use to work the function trim()

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
`str = str.replaceAll("[.]*[\\s\t]+$", "");`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your 3 methods, and them all work. I think your question describing not correctly or complete, in fact, a String in java would not like

```
String str = "abc*******         
      ********";
```

They must like

```
String str = "abc*******"         
      + "********";
```

So I think you should describe your question better to get help.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better served as a comment on the question? It doesn't really provide an answer.